# PHP Mostrar datos mysql

Tags: php

Quisiera saber porque me da error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Carga\php\valdad.php on line 2

```
 <?php
 $username=&_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];

 //conectar con la base de datos
  $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","login");
  $consulta="Select * from usuarios where username='$usuario' and 
  password='$password'";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
```

Gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: Cambia & por $ en la primera línea

Comment: Tienes un simbolo ampersan ( **&** ) donde recibes la variable *username* por post

Comment: Votada para cierre por: _Este problema contiene un error tipográfico._ Si  eliminas tú mismo la pregunta mucho mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Carga\php\valdad.php **on line 2**. La próxima vez fíjate más en el error, te suele dar bastante información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tipografia

```
<?php
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];

 //conectar con la base de datos
  $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","login");
  $consulta="Select * from usuarios where username='$usuario' and 
  password='$password'";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
```